# Nested queries in Apollo Server

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am building a GraphQL schema using `apollo-server`. My schema has a large number of queries and I would like to group them together. Is there a way to group them by domain, so that I could make queries like:

```
query {
  Books {
    getAll {
      ...
    }
    getByUser {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to do this with `graphql-dotnet`, but I'm not sure how to do this with `apollo-server`.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Apollo is a GraphQL client, so the queries that are available to you depend on the service you're querying. Are you asking about local state management (i.e. queries that use the `@client` directive)?

Comment: More importantly, asking for recommendations or "the best way" to do something tends to attract opinionated answers, which can make your question [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow. Please consider rewriting your question to ask either "how do I do x" or "what are the pros and cons of doing x", which would be more appropriate questions.

Comment: Apollo is client and server. But i am talking about server. Added it to main question.

Comment: Sorry Vytautas, it wasn't immediately clear you were talking about equivalent functionality in `apollo-server`. Thanks for clarifying and editing the question. I edited it again just to provide some additional details based on your comments and previous edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a schema like

```
type Query {
  books: Books
}

type Books {
  getAll: [Book!]!
}

type Book {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}
```

Your resolvers would need to look something like:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => {
      return {}
    },
  },
  Books: {
    getAll: () => {
      # return list of books
    }
  }
}
```

The `books` field returns an Object Type (`Books`), so it's resolver *must* return an object, even if it's an empty object as shown above. If the field resolves to null, none of its child fields will be resolved even if they are requested. By returning an empty object, we ensure the child fields will be resolved as well.

Comment: Maybe you can provide typescript example with GraphObjectType syntax?

Comment: Daniel thanks for an answer it works fine. I managed to do typescript version. Funny thing that it was not working for me because for some reason in typescript version empty resolve should return empty array and not an object: books : { type: Books, resolve: () => [] }. Any idea why? –

Comment: @VytautasPranskunas if you did `resolve: () => {}`, this is not returning an empty object -- it's a function with an empty body -- you'd have to do `resolve: () => ({})` if using an arrow function.

Comment: @VytautasPranskunas please accept the answer if you feel it sufficiently answered your question.